# Scodec - Coproducts could not find implicit value for parameter auto: scodec.codecs.CoproductBuilderAuto

Tags: scala, scodec

On version:

```
"org.typelevel" %% "scodec-core" % "1.5.0"
```

I'm trying to use coproduct functionality, as shown in the test case [demonstrate fixing the codec to a known subtype](https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/3f922e7c758db3cc17169a73cf69cb2b9de1ab74/unitTests/src/test/scala/scodec/examples/CoproductsExample.scala#L188).

I keep getting the error:  "could not find implicit value for parameter auto: scodec.codecs.CoproductBuilderAuto[my.class.here]"

I even copy pasted the example and could not get it to work:

```
import scalaz.\/
import shapeless._
import scodec.bits._
import scodec.codecs._
import scodec._

sealed trait Sprocket
object Sprocket {
  implicit val discriminated: Discriminated[Sprocket, Int] = Discriminated(uint8)
}

def codec(d: Int): Codec[Sprocket] = Codec.coproduct[Sprocket].discriminatedBy(provide(d)).auto
```

I'll continue to look into this on my end, but was wondering if there was an issue fixed around this lately.  I cloned the repo, and it worked from the clone - but not when I use the released version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error from the example code is caused by not having any subtypes of `Sprocket` defined. If there's at least 1 subtype of `Sprocket`, then Shapeless is able to generate a `LabelledGeneric[Sprocket]` instance where the representation is a discriminated union. The union is a coproduct of labelled subtypes.

Adding the following resolves the error:

```
case class Woozle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Sprocket
object Woozle {
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[Sprocket, Woozle, Int] = Discriminator(1)
  implicit val codec: Codec[Woozle] = (uint8 :: uint8).as[Woozle]
}
```

Note that you need both the `discriminator` and the `codec` implicits in the companion. If the `discriminator` isn't defined, you'll get the reported error. If the `codec` isn't defined, you'll get a diverging implicit error. Theoretically, the `Woozle` codec could be automatically derived if there's an implicit `Codec[Int]` in scope, but scalac isn't up to the task -- instead, it bails out with a diverging implicit expansion error. We hope to improve this with Shapeless 2.1.

For reference, full source:

```
import scalaz.\/
import shapeless._
import scodec.bits._
import scodec.codecs._
import scodec._

sealed trait Sprocket
object Sprocket {
  implicit val discriminated: Discriminated[Sprocket, Int] = Discriminated(uint8)
}

case class Woozle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Sprocket
object Woozle {
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[Sprocket, Woozle, Int] = Discriminator(1)
  implicit val codec: Codec[Woozle] = (uint8 :: uint8).as[Woozle]
}

object Main extends App {
  def codec(d: Int): Codec[Sprocket] = Codec.coproduct[Sprocket].discriminatedBy(provide(d)).auto
}
```

And build:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "scodec-core" % "1.5.0"
```

Comment: Aha!  Yeah it is a bit finicky...I had something similar in my real code, but I was defining my Codec.coproduct in-between Sprocket and Woozle, and thus the compiler didn't like it.  Putting it after the Woozle definition seemed to solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: For other who come here via google. You may need to import `scodec.codecs.implicits._` if you want `Codec` to me created automatically for your classes.