# Scodec: Coproducts could not find implicit value for parameter auto: scodec.codecs.CoproductBuilderAuto

Tags: scala, scodec

I am trying to define an Scodec coproduct codec for communicating with an EELink GPS.

Here is the code:

```
import scodec.Codec
import scodec.bits.ByteVector
import scodec.codecs._

trait Message
object Message {
  implicit val discriminated: Discriminated[ Message, Int ] = Discriminated(uint8)
  val codec: Codec[ Message ] = Codec.coproduct[ Message ].discriminatedByIndex(uint8)
}

case class GpsId(value: ByteVector)
object GpsId {
  val codec = bytes(8).as[ GpsId ]
}

case class SerialNumber(value: Int)
object SerialNumber {
  val codec = uint16.as[ SerialNumber ]
}

case class Header(protocolNumber: Int, length: Int, serial: SerialNumber)
object Header {
  val codec = (uint8 :: uint16 :: SerialNumber.codec).as[ Header ]
}

case class Login(header: Header, id: GpsId, language: Int) extends Message
object Login {
  val protocolNumber = 0x01
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[ Message, Login, Int ] = Discriminator(protocolNumber)
  implicit val codec: Codec[Login] = (Header.codec :: GpsId.codec :: uint8).as[ Login ]
}
```

I am getting the following:

```
Error:(14, 48) could not find implicit value for parameter auto: scodec.codecs.CoproductBuilderAuto[com.tecnoguru.ridespark.gps.eelink.messages.Message]
  val codec: Codec[ Message ] = Codec.coproduct[ Message ].discriminatedByIndex(uint8)
                                           ^
```

I have looked at [Scodec - Coproducts could not find implicit value for parameter auto: scodec.codecs.CoproductBuilderAuto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942003/scodec-coproducts-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-auto-scodec-cod) but it did not help, from what I see I am defining the codec and the discriminator correctly.

I am running on Scala 2.11.5 with scodec-core 1.7.0 and scodec-bits 1.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that is there now needs two minor changes:

1. The `Message` trait must be `sealed`, or otherwise, Shapeless will not provide a `Generic.Aux[Message, SomeCoproduct]` instance.
2. The call to `Codec.coproduct[Message]` must be after all the subtypes are defined. Moving the companion to the end of the file is sufficient.

With these two changes, the example compiles successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely missed the `sealed` keyword in https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/master/src/test/scala/scodec/examples/CoproductsExample.scala. However, that example does show the companion object defined at top of the file. Is the example wrong or is there something else at work?